How to visualize 3D model from vispy on tkinter canvas?
I am using Vispy to create 3D visualization. I use Tkinter for my GUI.
Are there any way to replace self.panel1 with Vispy Canvas? or embeded Vispy Canvas into self.panel1 (Tkinter canvas). In this code, the output give me 2 seperated windows.
def init_panels(self):
    self.panel1 = self.create_panel("3D", "white", "white")
    self.panel2 = self.create_panel("XY", "magenta", "yellow")
    self.panel3 = self.create_panel("YZ", "blue", "magenta")
    self.panel4 = self.create_panel("XZ", "blue", "yellow")

    self.panel1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    self.panel2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    self.panel3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    self.panel4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

    self.content_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=512)
    self.content_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=512)
    self.content_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=512)
    self.content_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=512)

    self.panels.extend([self.panel1, self.panel2, self.panel3, self.panel4])

    # Initial axes
    self.update_panel_images()

def create_panel(self, label_text, x_color, y_color):
    panel = Frame(self.content_frame, bg="black", width=512, height=512)
    panel.pack_propagate(False)  # Prevent the panel from resizing to fit its contents
    panel.canvas = Canvas(panel, bg="black")
    panel.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True, anchor="center")
    panel.bind("<Configure>", self.on_panel_resize)
    
    return panel

def visualize_vispy(self, volume3d):
    
    canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', show=True)
    view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
    
    volume = scene.visuals.Volume(volume3d, parent=view.scene, threshold=0.225)
    
    view.camera = scene.cameras.TurntableCamera(parent=view.scene, fov=60)
    view.camera.set_range()
    
    canvas.native.master = self.panel1
    canvas.native.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

In this code, I got this error.
AttributeError: 'CanvasBackendDesktop' object has no attribute 'pack'
I expect to visualize 3D model from Vispy in self.panel1
Is it possible?

Make sure you have the pyopengltk package installed as VisPy needs that to work with tk. Also note that this backend is experimental. The best I can give you for help is this original example code that the contributor who added Tk support to vispy used: https://gist.github.com/ThenTech/620d2422a8a2f2529d01bf34e229d7ca#file-tk_pyvis-py
